# How to write regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

**How to write regular expression for "abc xyx 12 13 a a b " ?**

In above

1. `abc xyx` is fixed keyword
2. `12` is first number that could be anything.
3. `13` is also any number that may change
4. `a` `b` `c` may also change

I have only to check this string start with `"abc xyz"` and after that two integer value available. i am using c#.net for this coding.

Comment: 4th one is unclear..

Comment: Is the requirement a space or whitespace between the words? Because the suggestions below match the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
abc\sxyx\s\d+\s\d+\s.*
```

if you want to extract the two integers here is the regex

```
abc\sxyx\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*
```

**[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI7yQ2/1)**

**C# sample**

```
    string hrefValue = "abc xyx 12 13 a a b ";
    Match m = Regex.Match(hrefValue, @"abc\sxyx\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*");
    Console.WriteLine("num 1: {0}, num 2: {1}", m.Groups[1].Value,  m.Groups[2].Value);
```

**[online demo](http://ideone.com/R9tebN)**

Comment: Thanks sir. can u please tell me how to use this with LINQ to check columns contains this format or not ?

Comment: @MANISH you can use `Regex.Match(hrefValue, @"abc\sxyx\s\d+\s\d+\s.*").Success` in where clause, if you have a linq prepared, I'll help you apply the same

Comment: @MANISH, I am glad it worked for you, you may now accept this answer to tell others that it worked for you. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that
- space could be one or more
- 12 is the first number that could be anything means fixed length of 2 digits
- 13 is also number that may change means the same as above I guess
- a b c also may change means charcter length is one with one or more space

```
/^abc\s+xyx\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\s+[a-z]\s+[a-z]\s+[a-z]/
```

Although it could be shorter but to make it simple I wrote like this.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jI1nJ8/1)

Comment: sir in above string "a b c d" is may change means right now only for charterer is there it may change to 6 7 8 that is not fixed.